# Why my sources are not available after I pushed changes to the production?

Tags: html, css

Something is wrong. When I open my site using localhost then everything is fine. What can be wrong here?

[image]

And when I click `assets/css/style.css` I got error like this:

[image]

When ew check Network tab, and click on style.css sotmething weird happens because html file is previewed:

[image]

Comment: Your `styles.css` URL appears to be an HTML document. There's nothing in your question that tells us what code determines what it should be.

Comment: @Quentin But it is not html document, it is css. Everything is fine when i run site on localhost.

Comment: Also, all your asset links should be absolute. Use `/assets/css/style.css` instead of `assets/css/style.css`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk — According to the network tab, it is an HTML document and not CSS.

Comment: @jdabtieu — While that is *generally* best practice, it isn't universally true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As myself and Quentin mentioned in the comments, it is *generally* good practice (and the intended effect for most situations) to use `/assets/path/to/resource` instead of the relative path `assets/path/to/resource`.

Unless it is intended to leave out that slash (which it isn't in your case, as you said in the comments), you'll need to prefix all the asset links with slashes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/scregal.css">
```

etc.

Answer (score -2):

There is only one possible causes of the problem I know although your question is not so clear.

1.》 Make sure the assets folder is in the same location as your html file.
》Prefix all your href link with a dot.  Check the image to see [image: image showing how to prefix link to css stylings]

I faced a problem like this when I wanted to push one of my electron apps to production mode. The dot makes it easy for the packager to load the whole folder.

Comment: What is that sideways picture of blurriness supposed to convey?

Comment: "Prefix all your href link with a dot" — What makes you think that the folder is called `.assets` and not `assets`? Did you mean `./`? That won't make a difference on the WWW.

Comment: "I wanted to push one of my electron apps to production mode. The dot makes it easy for the packager " — There's nothing in the question that suggests the OP is using electron or any kind of packager.